# BMI calculation, output using alertdialog

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem with my current source code. I'm quite new with this. It's about BMI calculation and will show output by using alertdialog. I have put the condition already but the output is always "You are OVERWEIGHT" on else condition even though my input was legit supposed to be IDEAL output.

The activity got no error in running but I got a feeling it's the calculation problem that I don't know. I am really sorry if this is a duplicate question.

```
public class BMIcalcu extends Activity{
    EditText weight, height;
    final Context context = this;
    Button calculate;
    float result, height1, weight1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.bmi_calcu);

      height = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
      weight = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
      calculate = (Button)findViewbyId(R.id.btn_bmi);

      String str1 = height.getText().toString();
      String str2 = weight.getText().toString();

      try{
        height1 = Float.parseFloat(str1)/100;
        weight1 = Float.parseFloat(str2);
        }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
          }

      calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                                   @Override
                                   public void onClick(View v){
        result = weight1 / (height1*height1);
        if(result<18.5){

          AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

          alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your BMI");

          alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("You are UNDERWEIGHT! START EATING!")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("List", new DialogInterface.OnClickLister(){
                                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
            Intent intent = new Intent(BMIcalcu.this, list.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
          })
                    .setNegativeButton("Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){

                      dialog.cancel();
                      }
        });
      AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
      alertDialog.show();

      }
else if(result<25){

          AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

          alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your BMI");

          alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("You are on your IDEAL!")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("List", new DialogInterface.OnClickLister(){
                                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
            Intent intent = new Intent(BMIcalcu.this, list.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
          })
                    .setNegativeButton("Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){

                      dialog.cancel();
                      }
        });
      AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
      alertDialog.show();
}
else{


          AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

          alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your BMI");

          alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("You are OVERWEIGHT! START EXERCISING!")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("List", new DialogInterface.OnClickLister(){
                                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
            Intent intent = new Intent(BMIcalcu.this, list.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
          })
                    .setNegativeButton("Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){

                      dialog.cancel();
                      }
        });
      AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
      alertDialog.show();
}
}
});
}
}
```

This is the xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<EditText
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:layout_width="266dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:inputType="text|number"
  android:hint="Height (Centimeter)"
  android:ems="10"
  android:id="@+id/editText1" />

<EditText
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:layout_width="266dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:inputType="text|number"
  android:hint="Weight (Kilogram)"
  android:ems="10"
  android:id="@+id/editText2"/>

<Button
  android:id="@+id/btn_bmi"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
  android:text="Calculate"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: your code looks good, can you give one example which according to you is correct but not working through code?

Comment: I input 157 as height, 50 as weight. It would be 20 as bmi (ideal). but it still print out as "overweight"

Comment: I suggest that you use the debugged to step through your code and view the values of your variables.

Comment: have you referenced right textView from xml for height and weight, paste the xml file

Comment: I think its something with the assignment. Sometimes you get wrong answer when you mix int and float/double. Maybe try to change this:
height1 = Float.parseFloat(str1)/100;
to this:
height1 = Float.parseFloat(str1)/100.0;

If it doesnt work, just try to debug.

Comment: @sanjeetkumarSingh edited the main post!

Comment: @EliranTutia apparently there's an error if i do that "Incompatible types, required float, found double"

Comment: everything looks good, try to debug and see what value you are getting after calculation

Comment: @HeatKaiC try to print the height1 variable after the assignment to check if its the problem.

Comment: height1 and weight1 are only set once, in the beginning of your `onCreate` method, which in turn is only called (once) when your activity is created. You want to move those lines with `height1 = Float.parseFloat...` into your `onClick` method.

Comment: @sanjeetkumarSingh debugging doesn't help :/

Comment: @EliranTutia I got a feeling what you said is similar to tiguchi and it's solved! Thank you for your time!

Comment: @tiguchi thank you so much for your time! you've saved me. Now everything is working perfectly.

Comment: @HeatKaiC oh, didnt see those both assignments are outside the listener. anyway, it works now. good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move height and weight assignment inside onClick().

```
calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
  String str1 = height.getText().toString();
  String str2 = weight.getText().toString();

  try{
    height1 = Float.parseFloat(str1)/100;
    weight1 = Float.parseFloat(str2);
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
      }

            result = weight1 / (height1*height1);
            String msg = "";
            if(result<18.5){
                msg = "You are UNDERWEIGHT! START EATING!";
            }
            else if(result<25){
                msg = "You are on your IDEAL!";
            }
            else{
                msg = "You are UNDERWEIGHT! START EATING!";
            }

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your BMI");

            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage(msg)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("List", new DialogInterface.OnClickLister(){
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(BMIcalcu.this, list.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){

                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your time sir!

Answer (score 0):

You're currently setting the values of `weight` and `height` inside the `onCreate()`. `onCreate` is called when the `Activity` is first created. `onCreate` is only called once in the Activity lifecycle. For more information on activities, go here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html.

To answer your question, you shouldn't be setting the values of `weight` and `height` in `onCreate` unless you are setting default values. Trying moving them into your `onClick` method:

```
calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        String str1 = height.getText().toString();
        String str2 = weight.getText().toString();

        try {
            height1 = Float.parseFloat(str1)/100;
            weight1 = Float.parseFloat(str2);
            result = weight1 / (height1*height1);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {

        }
        // Continue Alert Dialog stuff down here...
```

**Why are you having this problem?**

Currently, your `Activity` starts and `onCreate` is called. You are creating references to your xml and then trying to set the value of `weight` and `height`. However, when `onCreate` is called, the user has not yet entered anything into the `EditText` for either `weight` of `height`.
So, after that, suppose the user does enter values in. These values are not recorded anywhere. 
Then, when the user clicks the `Button` to see their BMI, you try to calculate the result. The result has nothing in it either therefore your `else` is always called. This is why you keep seeing the output that you do.